# Media is Write Protected

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, usb-flash-drive

I have sandisk 16 GB pendrive when fromat its shows an error media is wrtie protected.I search many tool & ways & trick but fail to fix this issue. Please if any one have solution please help me to get out from this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [USB Storage is Write-Protected](http://superuser.com/questions/166993/usb-storage-is-write-protected) and [Remove the write protection from a USB flash disk](http://superuser.com/questions/158083/remove-the-write-protection-from-a-usb-flash-disk) and [USB stick mysteriously become write protected](http://superuser.com/questions/689167/usb-stick-mysteriously-become-write-protected), [Pen Drive automatically got Write-Protected](http://superuser.com/questions/391397/pen-drive-automatically-got-write-protected), ...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem some weeks ago.

after checking many softwares (including diskpart in windows, Gparted in linux and some low-size programs which I dont remember the names!), but no one solved the problem!

finally I downloaded a software from the manufacturer website, which somehow reloaded the pendrive into factory settings.

I feel I solved the problem in a very hard way but by the way, the problem solved. (means not sure to be the easiest way)